`pm2` related commands in [Server] and [GitHub actions] are completely independent
Run pm2 related commands in [server] and [github actions] respectively, and the results obtained are completely independent. I don't know what happened. Running pm2 delete all on [github actions] will only delete the Processes on [github actions], I don’t know where these processes are specifically. You can still see the previous process list by running pm2 list on [server]
pm2 list result in server
pm2 list result in Github actions
[Server] and [Github actions] are both using the root user, and I tried running the whereis nodewhereis nvmwhereis pm2 command to see that the three environment variables are consistent.
I think they should run consistently
